# xamarin.forms set backgroundimage for page from file in android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an Image file that i create during runtime.

I want to set it as backgroundImage of a ContentPage (in android project)

I tried to set the path of the file to the BackgroundImage property but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it ?

I can't put it as resource since I create it at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Put your page into `Grid` which first element is an `Image`, then set that image `Source` to your stream like:

```
    Image bgImage = new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return new MemoryStream(buffer); });
    }

    Grid mainGrid = new Grid
    {
        Children = {bgImage,yourContent}
    };
    yourPage.Content= mainGrid;
```

Comment: It couldn't  be answer, because you propose workaround for solution. BackgroundImage propose to display image on page background. It works for Ios and UWP (Windows 10). Doesn't work for Android.

Comment: Dear Nuri,

If your image is in correct format it will work on all platforms, and also there should be a workaround for that because you cannot do it with current structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think that documentation is out of date. Becuase target Android has more than one resources.
as 
/drawable-hdpi
/drawable-xhdpi
etc.

So you should add your images for all folders  because it will work device. It Works.

*but I think that main issue on Xamarin.Forms
Becase drawable folder have to default images source when system couldn't find special resolution must select from default folder... *