# xamarin.forms set BackgroundImage from Image in android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a png i create at runtime.

Can I set it to BackgroundImage porperty of a page ?

I tried to insert the path of the file to the BackgroundImage  but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to Create Image class and set it to BackgroundImage ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xamarin.forms set backgroundimage for page from file in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665395/xamarin-forms-set-backgroundimage-for-page-from-file-in-android)

Comment: @asaf did you find any answer after one and half monthss later. I think that Xamarin.Forms has a bug for Android. But I want to be sure.